# BOT framework External client authentication

Tags: oauth-2.0, owin, botframework, access-token

I launch the client web application from the BOT framework to process the thrid party authentication. The client application process the the third party authentication using OAuth and Owin. Is there any way to send the useridentity back to the BOT framework?
 and able to get the access token from the client browser. But the same api call is not working from the BOT framework or from other client. (Ex: Httpget (clientappurl/api/GetToken)

Any ideas?

//api/GetToken ---GET

```
      public string GetToken()
{

   var identity = new ClaimsIdentity (User.Identity.AuthenticateType)
      identity.AddClaim ("sub", User.Identity.GetUserName()))
      AuthenticationTicket ticket  = new AuthenticationTicket (identity, 
      AuthenticationProperties());
      string token = Startup. OAuthOptions.AccessTokenFormat.Protect(ticket);
      return token;

}
```

Comment: Just to be sure of your architecture: the "client web application" is different from the web api project of your bot, right?

Comment: yes. IT is different and hosted in Azure and the OAuth is achieved through identity management and Owin middleware

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is called the [backchannel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-backchannel). There is an example in this link that may be all you need.  There is also another example here https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/blob/master/samples/backchannel/index.html. The backchannel will allow you to communicate between the client and the bot.

Comment: Thank you. But I need to allow the user to register in the Cortana App as well. Can we make custom OAuth provider as one of the connected service auth url and allow the user to register his credential to use it for single signon?  referane : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cortana/skills/authentication